# Show label value in segmented final image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'd like to show label value in final results displaying. I segmented input image using k means clustering and output are 25 classes.

My code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from skimage.segmentation import slic
 from skimage import color
 
 
 img_bounds = slic(img_blurred,          # filtered input image
                    n_segments=25,
                    compactness=1,
                    start_label=0)
 
 plt.figure()
 plt.gray()
 plt.subplot(121)
 plt.imshow(img_rounded)                 # input image
 plt.subplot(122)
 plt.imshow(color.label2rgb(img_bounds, img_blurred_normalized, alpha=0.5))
```

`img_bounds` contains labels for every class.

Whole code produces this output: [Segmented image using Scikit-image slic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMjIj.png)

Finally, here is my question. I'd like to plot class number insude right plot, so, f.e. in center of each class appears its label. Do you have any idea, how could I achieve it?

I tried to look for function, which would do this on Matplotlib.pyplot and also on Scikit-image APIs, but I did not find any relevant informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to write a full answer at the moment, but your variable `img_bounds` will have `1` where the pixel is of class 1, and `2` where the pixel is of class 2 and so on...

You can make a binary image of the pixels in, say, class 4 with:

```
c4 = ((img_bounds == 4) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

import cv2
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-class4.png', c4)
```

That will give you a solid black image that just has pixels of class=4 in white and save it in a debug image with **OpenCV**. You can then use **OpenCV** again to find that contour and to find its centroid:

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(c4, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

You can then get the moments with:

```
M = cv2.moments(cnts[0])
```

And then get the centroid of the class 4 pixels with:

```
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

You can then draw text near that point `[cX,cY]` with:

```
cv2.putText()
```

or with PIL/Pillow.

Repeat for other classes. Or take the max and min x and y and draw in geometric centre rather than at centroid.